# Output of power function differs whether value comes from a variable or a fix number

Tags: c

I'm trying to decompose a number into its digits, and a method that works when manually assigning values doesn't when I replace these values with (I would think) equivalent variables. Here is the relevant code.
This outputs "5, 9, 6":

```
    printf("%d\n", 695 % (int) pow(10, 1) / (int) pow(10, 0));
    printf("%d\n", 695 % (int) pow(10, 2) / (int) pow(10, 1));
    printf("%d\n\n", 695 % (int) pow(10, 3) / (int) pow(10, 2));
```

yet this outputs "5, 0, 7":

```
    int n = 695, m = 1;
    printf("%d\n", n % (int) pow(10, m) / (int) pow(10, m - 1)); m++;
    printf("%d\n", n % (int) pow(10, m) / (int) pow(10, m - 1)); m++;
    printf("%d\n", n % (int) pow(10, m) / (int) pow(10, m - 1));
```

Since the pow() function takes doubles as inputs I've tried casting m to a double, but this also gives "5, 0, 7". n has to be an integer for modulo operator to work, and replacing instances of n with '695' also fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point calculation may contain errors.

When wrong output is produced because the errors lead to unintended truncation to smaller integers, adding small values can reduce chance to get wrong output due to the errors.

Try this:

```
int n = 695, m = 1;
double EPS = 1e-7;
printf("%d\n", n % (int) (pow(10, m)+EPS) / (int) (pow(10, m - 1)+EPS)); m++;
printf("%d\n", n % (int) (pow(10, m)+EPS) / (int) (pow(10, m - 1)+EPS)); m++;
printf("%d\n", n % (int) (pow(10, m)+EPS) / (int) (pow(10, m - 1)+EPS));
```